# Inconsistent results when overriding filterAcceptsRow in QFileDialog

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm trying to create a `QFileDialog` with filtering on the file extension and file name. The file extension can be filtered via `setNameFilter()`, but name filtering (as far as I know) can only be filtered by creating a custom dialog and proxy model and then overriding the `filterAcceptsRow()` function.

I should be returning `True` when I want a file to show up in the dialog and `False` when I don't. The trouble is that when I return based on the custom checking I get no results. But when I return `True` always (even when I execute the check and print out based on it), I see all of the expected files. If it weren't for the printout I'd think I'm creating the pattern improperly, but that's not the case. And each button that opens this dialog sends a different value for `file_part` so I can't hard-code the pattern.

I have replaced my first attempt at example code with a toy example that hopefully showcases the problem. In my test environment, `C:\temp\` contains the following files:

- `0bbb_record2_part1.txt`
- `0bbb_record2_part2.txt`
- `0jjj_record1_part1.txt`
- `0jjj_record1_part2.txt`
- `0jjj_record2_part1.txt`
- `0jjj_record2_part2.txt`
- `0jjj_record3_part1.txt`
- `0jjj_record2_part2.txt`

```
import sys
import re

from PyQt5 import Qt, QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class FileFilterProxyModel(QtCore.QSortFilterProxyModel):
  def __init__(self, file_part, parent = None):
    super(FileFilterProxyModel, self).__init__(parent)
    self.__pattern = re.compile(f'0{file_part}_record2')

  def filterAcceptsRow(self, source_row, srcidx):
    model = self.sourceModel()
    index0 = model.index(source_row, 0, srcidx)
    file_name = model.fileName(index0)

    if model.isDir(srcidx):
      return True

    return self.__pattern.search(file_name.lower()) != None

class MyFilePicker(QFileDialog):
  def __init__(self, file_part):
    super().__init__()
    self.setWindowTitle('Filtered File Picker')
    self.setOption(QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog)
    self.setNameFilter('Record 2 Files (*.txt)')
    self.setDirectory('C:\\temp\\')
    self.setFileMode(QFileDialog.ExistingFile)
    self.setAcceptMode(QFileDialog.AcceptOpen)
    self.setProxyModel(FileFilterProxyModel(file_part, self))

if __name__ == '__main__':
  app = QApplication(sys.argv)
  fp = MyFilePicker('jjj')
  fp.show()
  fp.exec_()
```

Currently all files are passing the filter while I would expect only `0jjj_record2_part1.txt` and `0jjj_record2_part2.txt` to be displayed.

Comment: I've updated my included code to hopefully qualify as a minimal reproducible example. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that if you are filtering the i-th file in the folder then srcidx will point to the directory so `isDir()` will always return True when filtering files. The solution is to change with index0:

```py
def filterAcceptsRow(self, source_row, srcidx):
    model = self.sourceModel()
    index0 = model.index(source_row, 0, srcidx)
    file_name = model.fileName(index0)
    if model.isDir(index0):
        return True
    return self.__pattern.search(file_name.lower()) is not None
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're filtering everything, including the directory that is going to be shown. If the current selected path doesn't match the regex, then the index for that path won't be accepted, and the result would be an empty file dialog (since that path "doesn't exist").

A possible solution is to check that if the index is a directory:

```
    def filterAcceptsRow(self, source_row, srcidx):
        model = self.sourceModel()
        index0 = model.index(source_row, 0, srcidx)
        if model.isDir(index0):
            return True
        # ...
```

This will also solve the issue of folders inside the current directory, which wouldn't be visible, thus preventing the user to browse them.

If, for some reason, you don't want that, you can check whether the current directory of the dialog matches the parent of the index:

```
class FileFilterProxyModel(QtCore.QSortFilterProxyModel):
    def __init__(self, file_part, dialog):
        super(FileFilterProxyModel, self).__init__(dialog)
        self.__pattern = re.compile(f'^0{file_part}_')
        self.dialog = dialog

    def filterAcceptsRow(self, source_row, srcidx):
        model = self.sourceModel()
        if self.dialog.directory().absolutePath() != model.filePath(srcidx):
            return True
        index0 = model.index(source_row, 0, srcidx)
        file_name = model.fileName(index0)
        return self.__pattern.search(file_name.lower()) != None
```

But consider that this would cause some issues: if the user tries to access the parent directory, the child directory won't be visible from there.

Comment: I'm clearly doing more wrong here than I thought. When I try to implement your first recommendation and check to see if the index is a directory I wind up accepting all files again. And when I print out the srcidx object it is always pointing to the same location in memory.

Comment: @Justin don't rely on the index pointer. Have you correctly added the remaining code when using first example? In any case, I suggest you to edit your question and provide a MRE as already requested in the comments, so that we'll be able to safely test it without modifications that could change the result on our side.

Comment: Hi again - I think I've updated the example code to be more complete (it executes as a standalone script for me - hopefully it does for others, too). Thanks for helping me out so far!

Comment: @Justin as eyllanesc pointed out, I mistakenly checked the parent index only instead of the actual index, and since the parent is always a directory, it would always return True. I fixed my answer accordingly, as I was able to properly test it with the MRE (and that's another reason for which it's always better to provide one).